In AvaloniaUI, how to render without clearing
I am using a RenderTargetBitmap. I have a piece of code like this
using (var context = WorldImage.CreateDrawingContext()) {
    Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
    context.DrawLine(pen, previousPoint, currentPoint);
}

The purpose of this code is two draw a curve by pairs of points. However, it doesn't work because it clears the image before each draw. How to disable this clearing?


How to disable this clearing?

You can't. You must instead keep all the points that should be drawn, e.g. in a collection of Points.
It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. The following sample draws a polyline that follows the mouse cursor as long as the left mouse button is pressed.
With an Image element in XAML
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="None"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>

the code below would draw the polyline. Note that in Avalonia there seems to be no automatic UI update when a RenderTargetBitmap is redrawn, hence the InvalidateVisual() on the Image element.
private readonly RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new(new PixelSize(400, 400));
private readonly List<Point> polyline = [];

public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    image.Source = bitmap;
    image.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
    image.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;
}

private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerPressedEventArgs e)
{
    polyline.Clear();
    polyline.Add(e.GetPosition(image));
}

private void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerEventArgs e)
{
    var p = e.GetCurrentPoint(image);

    if (p.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
    {
        polyline.Add(p.Position);

        using var context = bitmap.CreateDrawingContext();

        Pen pen = new(Brushes.Black);

        for (int i = 1; i < polyline.Count; i++)
        {
            context.DrawLine(pen, polyline[i - 1], polyline[i]);
        }

        image.InvalidateVisual();
    }
}

